# Downloading site from old.nasdaq.com works with curl but fails with RestSharp/Httpclient

Tags: curl, web-scraping, restsharp

To download the most active stocks infos I download the page `https://old.nasdaq.com/markets/most-active.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ` using RestSharp:

```cs
var url = "https://old.nasdaq.com/markets/most-active.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ";
var client = new RestClient(url)
{
    UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"
};

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<string>(request);
```

A couple of days ago it stopped working however. Now I only receive the following error:

```
An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
```

I also tried with `HttpClient` and with `HtmlAgilityPack`, but with the same result. However retrieving the site with curl works like a charm:

```
curl https://old.nasdaq.com/markets/most-active.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"
```

Obviously NASDAQ improved their scraping detection. It used to be sufficient to just set the user agent.

But why is curl still working?
Where's the difference to what RestSharp does?
An how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This should really be a comment, but because I don't have enough reputation, I'll answer instead. I have tried to reach this URL at different times with both CURL and WGET, and it always times out.

I've also tried to reach the similar `https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download`, and it also times out. Based on the `https://old.nasdaq.com/robots.txt` file in place now, I'd say Nasdaq really discourages programmatic downloads.

While I am not aware of any other URL that would permit the download of a similar spreadsheet, I think with a modest amount of web scraping, you'll be able to restore the functionality from any number of web sites.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The robots.txt seems to be absolutely restrictive as all user agent are blocked. But how can I access the website with my browser then?